# Ubuntu 11.04 pam_userdb.so missing

Tags: ubuntu, pam, ftp

We just upgraded Ubuntu Server 10.10 to 11.04. After this upgrade, it seems Vsftpd with pam_userdb logins no longer work. I was investigating this and it seems /lib/security/pam_userdb.so is missing.

This is very strange, and even if I do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpam-modules` it is still missing.

Any idea what is going on? Is this a known bug or is there something wrong on our end?

P.S. Vsftpd with userdb logins was working fine with at least 3 previous versions of Ubuntu, now this 11.04 upgrade seems to have broken it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[packages.u.c](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=natty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=pam_userdb.so) tells us that `pam_userdb.so` exists in `libpam-modules` in architecture dependent paths. As a quick workaround, you can install a compatibility symlink:

```
ln -s /lib/*-linux-gnu/security/pam_userdb.so /lib/security/pam_userdb.so
```

To solve the problem for real, you need to determine why vsftpd/pam uses the wrong path to lookup the modules. Check for non-upgraded packages or hung processes first. Since all modules in `libpam-modules` are located in the arch-specific directory I would point to vsftpd in the first place, since other parts of your system seem to work fine with the new location.

P.S.: Don't forget to remove the symlink if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! pam_userdb.so indeed exists in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/pam_userdb.so. It would have been a good idea to update /etc/pam.d/vsftpd to look the pam_userdb.so in that location. But I actually migrated logins to libpam-pwdfile format. I was in a bit hurry to get ftp logins up and running, so I did a quick login credential backend migration.

Answer (score 0):

THanks for the help!!! it works for me when i change the path of the pam_userdb.so file in

/etc/pam.d/vsftpd from /lib/security/pam_userdb.so

to /lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/pam_userdb.so

it works fine whit the current users, but the only detail is when i try to create new virtual users, vsftpd don't recognize them

do you have a solution for this?

thanks